# Declare sub class method parameters to be more specific (without implementation) in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, can I do the following thing in TS ?
I just want to narrow down the input type in sub class for better IDE auto-completion. And I don't want to write the implementation in it like `super.foo(a)`.
(Actually, I'm sub-classing EventEmitter of node and want to narrow down the eventName of on and emit)

```js
class Base {
    foo (a: string){
        // Do many things
    }
}

class Child {
    // I want to declare that this foo method can only accept these strings, and reuse the Base class's implementation
    declare foo (a: 'AAA'|'BBB'); 
}
```

I know there is a [Type-only Field Declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#type-only-field-declarations), which is very handy by adding a `declare` before a class field to just re-declare a more accurate type for an inherited field.
So I wonder if there is a way to do that for an inherited method.

Comment: You're looking for something inherently unsafe, but TS supports bivariant methods so I guess it's fine (but can cause runtime errors, so be careful). No, there is no way to do this without reimplementing the method; see the feature request at [ms/TS#38003](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38008).  The "right" way to do this is with generics, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7Vlow) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If you are extending EventEmitter, consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-emitter types-only package to add types to EventEmitter

Comment: @jcalz Yes. Thank you for providing the GitHub issue link! You addressed my question. So I know the answer is definitely no. I will write some implementation in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently use [the `declare` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) on methods. There's an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#38008](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38008), but for now it's not part of the language.  That means you'd need to work around it either by reimplementing the overriding method:

```
class Child extends Base {
    foo(a: 'AAA' | 'BBB') {
        super.foo(a);
    }
}
```

or by changing from a method to a function-valued property:

```
class Base {
    foo = (a: string) => {
        // Do many things
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    declare foo: (a: 'AAA' | 'BBB') => void;
    //      ~~~ <-- error with --strictFunctionTypes
}
```

Of course here you will see that if [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) is enabled (part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)), you get an error.  It's unsafe to have a child class assume that the argument to `foo()` is *more specific* than its parent expects.  That violates *contravariance* of parameter types (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)), which can end up biting you if you're not careful:

```
class Whoops extends Child {
    foo(k: 'AAA' | 'BBB') {
        ({ AAA: 1, BBB: 2 })[k].toFixed(1);
    }
}
function acceptBase(base: Base) { base.foo("oops") };
acceptBase(new Whoops()); // RUNTIME ERROR
```

Let's assume that you will be careful.

---

Right now the only way to support this sort of thing is to make `Base` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the parameter to `foo()`, and then specify the type argument for your subclass:

```
class Base<A extends string = string> {
    foo(a: A) {
        // Do many things
    }
}

class Child extends Base<"AAA" | "BBB">{ }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCBLMMA2FLABckBvAKAEh5sQookAhG5M88gMwHsOAKEALiRQCAJ3TAA5gEoSFVgHo5SACIckYEMACeSAgAsx4qLIC+FUxSo06AYX3YAJkggAPAhGD26jKM1mce-EgA5ACCYUFIAD7B9LFB0iysUACuMBDCAHT+vJIA3CZmpEWU1LRIAOq6XDB0Lm4eNnaOidkA1gKh4VExcQmy5NzESGEhAgCMADQMsQIATEjGkgDarQC6GQQcAGLozhD23GN5BeSm7MnA8AToHMBICIgwBN4Q3ABGTAIvCUgfPllcbgAImqUCB0mM+XIDwgTxe3GAEAA7hUqhwatxJHkkApUABVAByABUAJIAWQAokgKSgUAB5FCkcygSCwBDILYXeAANRA2AACsJ0TILKUvEwZKx-EgALxIXgCISiCTSGUAPkl8kUKjUGm0egMRlYZ3MJSsSFs6AcTlc7k8DAliXsEEswmQ-gECuCIwi0SCsXo8VlGoAbhx0PYoeRcUhY7GAH6JpAAHgAtKmnMIhcIkEj0HokOmlegrpzLtdbkTNGkjeYmUUWdA4IgkABxdzpEsis1lF7JkI2+r24sSWWCEQGDUtQGBEJ9VjR7WqdRaHT6CRG06FUXmy3Wup28U+ZNAkZA7pAgNAtVDU1MoA)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!  I also realized that what I want will violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype, [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170138)).